# Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379/0: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused

Tags: django, heroku, redis, celery

I've deployed a minimal django/celery/redis project to heroku, and I'm trying to test it in the python shell:

```
 heroku run python

 >>> import tasks
 >>> tasks.add.delay(1, 2)
```

The problem is tasks.add.delay(1,2) doesn't produce any output, it just hangs there whereas in local it gave an Async message.

Also when i try to see the task running in application logs with "heroku logs -t -p worker"

it gives me this error:

```
   ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379/0: Error 111      
   connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
```

PS. It works fine on local.

Comment: Can you show your *settings* where to configure *celery*?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i was missing the following in my tasks.py file in my application directory.

```
   import os
   app.conf.update(BROKER_URL=os.environ['REDIS_URL'],
            CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=os.environ['REDIS_URL'])
```

added that and now everything works.

Comment: you could place them in `settings.py`